# Prove that $d_n>(n-1)!$ for all $n\geq4$.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

**Problem:** Prove that $d_n>(n-1)!$ for all $n\geq4$.

$d_n$comes from the derangement where $$d_n=(n-1)(d_{n-1}+d_{n-2})=n!\sum_{m=0}^{n}\dfrac{(-1)^m}{m!}=n!\Bigg(1-\frac{1}{1!}+\frac{1}{2!}-\cdots +\dfrac{(-1)^n}{n!}\Bigg)$$
I've used induction, but do not have a solid proof, yet. Any ideas?

Comment: if the recurrence holds, then the statement is true by induction. Are you asking if the recurrence is true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strong induction:

$n=4$, do the math

now, by strong induction apply disequality to $d_{n-1}$ and $d_{n-2}$: $d_n = (n-1)(d_{n-1} + d_{n-2}) > (n-1)((n-2)! + (n-3)!) = (n-1)! + (n-1)(n-3)! $

Now remove the second term, you get a $d_n > (n-1)!$

Comment: You don’t even need strong induction: since $d_n\ge 0$, you can argue that if $d_n>(n-1)!$, then $$d_{n+1}=n(d_n+d_{n-1})\ge nd_n>n(n-1)!=n!\;.$$